# Best method of using jquery load and re-loading a script at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table that uses jquery's .load function to reload all of the data in the table after something is moved.

The issue is that when the table loads, the external javascript files on the page aren't being used in the table any longer.

To resolve this issue myself, i've started using jquery's .getScript. This works (sometimes), but it's not working well. I think the script is taking a long time to load whereas the table instantly loads, resulting in the scripts messing up sometimes.

I've also tried using a function after the getScript which still seems to not work properly.

This is what i'm using currently

```
    $(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            update: function(event, ui) {
                serial = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
                $.ajax({
                url: "./menu-controller.php",
                type: "post",
                data: serial,
                success: function() {
                    $.getScript("./menu-admin.js");
                    $("#sortable").load("./menu-manager.php #menu-table");
            },
                error: function(){
                    alert("A problem occurred when moving this menu item. Please try again or contact support.");
                }
                });
            },
        handle:'.move-item',
        connectWith:'#menu-table',
        placeholder: "highlight",
        containment: "parent",
        revert: true,
        tolerance: "pointer",
        items: 'tbody > *'
        });
    });
```

Specifically, we're looking at the "success" of the update of .sortable. Is there any better solutions to this?

My ultimate goal would be to have the script fully loaded before the table starts to load. And again, i've already tried using a function of getScript, this didn't seem to work.

I appreciate any advice, tips, or solutions provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **get()** only with a callback as such:

```
$.get('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3.1.0/ext-core.js', function(response){
  // Start table
});
```